# simple gravity train in python

Tags: python, physics, gravity

I want to write a program describes in simple the movement of the apple through the earth,  or what we call *Gravity train* 
,see (Gravity train by wikipedia)  [Gravity train by hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mechanics/earthole.html)

*I want to draw movement speed and postion in the time.*

This is my code that I made, but I got wrong answer ( wrong value for speed and time). although I used right the equations for a falling body [falling body Equations wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_for_a_falling_body)  and the acceleration figuure is good but stay the value for velocity and distance that I got is very big
what is my wrong ?
Thanks in advance 
Max

**What the value that I must have
The time must be equals 2530.30 seconds (nearly 42.2 minutes)
The maximum speed is about 7 900 metres per second (28440 km/h).

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Max Oceaan 2015 10 5
# Gravity train program

# Please notice that we assume ::
# -- air friction is neglected
# -- gravitational constant = 6.67408 × 10-11
# -- Earth  Mass M  5.972 × 10^24 kg


# -- the apple speed in begin is 0 (free fall)
v=0

# -- the begin time is zero
t=0


L_t=[] # list for time step
L_h=[] # list for postion (hight)
L_v=[] # list for Velocity
L_g=[] # list for acceleration

r=6371000   #Earth radius per meter
delta=100    # Length step that we walk in for_loop
for h in np.arange(0.1,2*r,delta):

# c is the correction factor for g is 
# distance of apple from center of earth / earth radius
#notice:: when the apple reach the earth center c will be negativ en -1
    c=float((r-h)/r)

# acceleration is according to law of Newten
    g= float(6.67408 * (10**-11) * 5.972 * (10**24)*(c) )/(r**2)

# time  is t=t+math.sqrt(2*(delta)/g)
# en speed is v=v+math.sqrt(2*(delta)g)
    # But must g positive and if g negative ,the laws are as follows:
# t= t + math.sqrt(2*(delta)/(abs(g)))     v=v - math.sqrt(2*(delta)*(abs(g)))
    if g>0:
        t=t+math.sqrt(2*delta/g)
        v=v+math.sqrt(2*delta*g)
    else:
        t=t + math.sqrt(2*delta/(abs(g))) 
        v=v - math.sqrt(2*delta*(abs(g)))


    L_h.append(h)
    L_t.append(t)
    L_v.append(v)
    L_g.append(g)


plt.subplot(121) 
plt.title("Velocity ")  
plt.xlabel("Time ") 
plt.ylabel("Velocity m/s") 
plt.plot(L_t, L_v, 'g-')


plt.subplot(122)
plt.title("distance ") 
plt.xlabel("Time ") 
plt.ylabel("distance  m") 
plt.plot(L_t, L_h, 'b-')

plt.tight_layout()


plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(L_t, L_g , 'b-')
plt.title("acceleration in tijd") 
plt.xlabel(" Time s") 
plt.ylabel("acceleration (a) m/ss") 


plt.show()
```

I have tried to improve it but I got worse result in the graphic 
the new code

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Please notice that we assume :air friction is neglected

G = 6.67408 * (10**-11)     # gravitational constant
M = 5.972 * (10**24)        # Earth  Mass in kg
r = 6371000                 # Earth radius per meter
p = 5514                    # Mean Earth density in kg\m3

time = 0   #  the begin time is zero
a=0     #  the begin acceleration g 
v=0
t=0

L_h = [] # list for postion (hight)
L_a = [] # list for acceleration
L_v = [] # list for speed
L_t = [] # list for time

# for_loop in the path that we walk
delta=1000
for h in np.arange(1,2*r,delta):

# (M_effective) is The effective mass of earth that changes when h changes 
# (M_effective) =         new sphere volume       * density
#    M_effective = (4./3) * (math.pi) * ((r-h)**3)   *  p
    M_effective = (4./3) * (math.pi) *   p * (math.pow((r-h),3))


    a = G * M_effective / (r**2)  # (a) is the acceleration 

    if a>0:
        a=a
        t=t+math.sqrt(2*delta/a)
        v=v+math.sqrt(2*delta*a)
    else:
        a=a
        t=t + math.sqrt(2*delta/(abs(a))) 
        v=v - math.sqrt(2*delta*(abs(a)))


    L_h.append(h)
    L_t.append(t)
    L_v.append(v)
    L_a.append(a)




plt.subplot(121) 
plt.title("Velocity ")  
plt.xlabel("Time ") 
plt.ylabel("Velocity m/s") 
plt.plot(L_t, L_v, 'g-')


plt.subplot(122)
plt.title("distance ") 
plt.xlabel("Time ") 
plt.ylabel("distance  m") 
plt.plot(L_t, L_h, 'b-')

plt.tight_layout()


plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(L_t, L_a , 'b-')
plt.title("acceleration in tijd") 
plt.xlabel(" Time s") 
plt.ylabel("acceleration (a) m/ss") 


plt.show()
#Gravity train
#The travel time equals 2530.30 seconds (nearly 42.2 minutes),
#For a train that goes directly through the center of the Earth, the maximum speed is about 7 900 metres per second (28440 km/h).
```

Comment: Good job so far, max! keep working at it. Here's a couple of hints. One is on your data structures and approach. You probably want to develop `x(t)`, `v(t)`, even `a(t)` to plot, so that you can determine what these dynamics values are for any `t`. Then you should also be able to verify your results by determining which `t` you get `v(t)` and `a(t)` = 0. Those are your sanity checks. And you can check the corresponding `x(t)` for those zeroes. so, once you have that right in your head, you might consider building out arrays of numbers which are the values at the different `t`, 1D arrays. :)

Comment: You are doing the integration wrong. The equations that you've copied from Wikipedia are integral - they apply to a body that is falling down in a constant gravity field and that is initially motionless. You should turn them into differential form by taking the derivative with respect to the distance travelled. Note that an analytic expression for `v(r)` is easily obtainable from the energy conservation law.